# Tabbar Controller with swipe effect

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to do a Tabbar Controller like below effect:

[image]

By swiping an viewcontroller will redirect to next tab. How can we achieve this in iOS? Is there any other controls to do like this?

Comment: you can use UIScrollview with containment view controller i. e. addchildViewcontroller menthod...

Comment: @Kalpesh Is there any sample code related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add   UISwipeGestureRecognizer to your tabBarView controller and change your tabBar index after swipe.

```
swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                      action:@selector(swipeMethod:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; 
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
```

And my method to handle swipe is :

```
-(void)swipeMethod: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe!");   
}
```

**EDIT**
Or you can use `UIScrollView` with paging enable and `UIView` to display your data.

Here is the tutorial you are looking for [Tabbar Controller with swipte effect](http://code4app.net/ios/%E9%80%89%E9%A1%B9%E5%8D%A1%E6%BB%91%E5%8A%A8%E6%95%88%E6%9E%9C/503642036803fa9e55000002)

Comment: I know this will work. But, this won't give the effect which i expect.

Comment: which effect you are expecting?

Comment: Like android mobile play store

Comment: you can use `UIScrollView` with paging enable and `UIView` to display your data.

Comment: I have found [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hmsegmentedcontrol) in this can we do what i expect. In my app, i have to show 3 tableview with three tabs. How do i do that with this swipe?

Comment: Yes you were right. Use of `UIScrollView` and its paging method giving desired output.

Comment: My answer. I've answered for this question.

Comment: @Praveen check my edited anser... there is an tutorial you are looking for

Comment: Nice tutorial.. Thanks.. I expected like this

Comment: Its in my profile. You can check there. Anyway i can tell here, am from bangalore.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for this on GitHub, it is called MGSwipeTabBarController and is designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

It is as simple as :

```
NSArray *viewControllers = . . . //your view controllers
MGSwipeTabBarController *swipeController = [[MGSwipeTabBarController alloc] initWithViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Please Note that it is only compatible with iOS7 and + and that you'll still need to design your own tab bar that respond to scroll events using the `MGSwipeTabBarControllerDelegate`protocol.

https://github.com/mglagola/MGSwipeTabBarController

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView
you can use this class to achieve your goal...

or else you have to make animation for tap on tabbar using following method,

```
[UIView transitionFromView:<#(UIView *)#> toView:<#(UIView *)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#> completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>]
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is still looking you can find another implementation here on this youtube series

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xv1mJvwXok&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj

**Edit:**

1. So to my knowledge and according to the video, the idea is that you'll want to use two `UICollectionViews` in one view controller. One collection view to display the content (apps) and the other for the horizontal navigation containing the categories.
2. To create the green 'highlight' bar you can use a `UIView` and adjust the height/width of the bar using `constraints - heightAnchor/widthAnchor` and add that to the navigation bar.
3. To get the bar moving with the distance the user will swipe, there is a method you can override to capture the horizontal scrolling called `scrollViewDidScroll`. From here you'll want to provide a variable from your the `UIView`'s constraint (of type `NSLayoutConstraint`) to be able to update the x position of the `UIView`

   ```
   override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 
   {
       print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
       menuBar.myGreenBarLeftConstraint.constant = scrollView.contentOffset.x / 4 
       //or however many categories you have
   }
   ```